# MinGW 4.7.0 to 4.7.2 bug: Invalid "this" pointer in member functions when using mixed virtual and non-virtual multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, mingw, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have code with inheritance that looks like this:

```
        B
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    BI      D
(template) /
      \   /
       \ /
        DI
    (template)
```

`[B]ase` and `[D]erived` are interfaces that both contain a `static` method `create()`, which returns an instance of the respective implementation, `BaseImpl` or `DerivedImpl`.
The implementations are templates, and the factory methods choose how to instantiate them at runtime. The code below is a working example of my program's logic.

The problem is, in my real code, `Base` methods get a faulty `this` pointer and inevitably crash. I have examined the assembly code right before the call to one of the methods, which takes no arguments, in both real and example code, and found that it differs:

**Working (example) code**

```
call   <std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> >::operator->() const>
mov    (%eax),%edx
add    $0x8,%edx
mov    (%edx),%edx
mov    %eax,%ecx
call   *%edx
```

The above translates to a `base->method()` call, where `base` is a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.
For those that don't know, the calling convention of class methods can be a [__thiscall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx), which it in this case is. That means that `this` isn't passed on the stack, but is stored in `ecx`. The code above simply stores `this` into `ecx`, and then locates `method()`, stores its address into `edx`, and calls it. Everything works as it should.

**Faulty (real) code**

```
call   <std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> >::operator->() const>
mov    (%eax),%edx
add    $0x18,%edx
mov    (%edx),%ebx
lea    -0x24(%ebp),%edx
mov    %eax,(%esp)
movl   $0x9,-0x9c(%ebp)
mov    %edx,%ecx
call   *%ebx
```

This is the exact same `base->method()` call. The address of `method()` is stored into `ebx` this time. `this`, however, is loaded from an arbitrary place off the stack!? The program, as expected, crashes. Anyone knows why would the compiler generate assembly like that? I'm still trying to figure it out.

## Code

The example code is below. The real code crashes at a point analogous to the example's call to `base->check()` from `invoker->invoke()`.

*Code removed to conserve space. To view it, check the edit history.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ pointer multi-inheritance fun](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157104/c-pointer-multi-inheritance-fun)

Comment: The `this` pointer doesn't have to stay the same inside different derived classes. If you need the base address of the outermost object you can use `dynamic_cast<const void *>` iirc.

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes, you're absolutely right. The code I've posted doesn't reproduce the error I have in my real code. The address of `this` pointer in the real code is way out of bounds of the program's virtual memory, eg. `0x429bce8` vs `0x7a55ec`. I'll try to figure out what's happening.

Comment: @n.m. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: It's a completely different question now.

Comment: @n.m. The question is about the same problem, even though it's slightly reformulated now. I've just changed the information as I researched deeper into the problem. But it wasn't even close to being a duplicate of [C++ pointer multi-inheritance fun](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2157104/2006222) to begin with.

Comment: I call it "totally rewritten" rather than "slightly reformulated", but whatever works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. ([55173](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55171), [55367](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55367), [55453](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55453)) The bug is specific to `gcc-i686-mingw` versions `4.7.0` to `4.7.2`.

From [55173](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55171):

> When a virtual call invoked on an object which uses both virtual and non-virtual inheritance, the virtual thunk leaves the target function with an invalid "this" pointer.

It's basically what I've described in the question. The register that should hold `this` was used in non-related operations.

The only solution is to downgrade below `4.7.0` or upgrade to `4.7.3` or above.