# C++ : *this changes value between calls

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

So I was debugging a program that was showing a Segfault. I ran gdb and from the backtrace I see that the value of (this) changes on calling.

The calling function is of the type

```
Foo::funcName1() const {
    return Bar::funcName2()->calledFunc();
}
```

The called function is of the form

```
Foo2::calledFunc() const {
    /*
     Some stuff
    */
}
```

According to the backtrace I have

```
0x00007ff456a9ec9f in Blah::Meh::funcName1() const (this=0x1f59b40)
0x00007ff44fee181c in Foo2::calledFunc() const (this=0x0)
```

How can this be happening ?

Comment: Since you're having a seg fault, it's probably safe to say that whatever is causing the error is going to mess up many things - including internal pointers

Comment: Could you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? The code snippets you show doesn't really tell us anything. All we can guess is that `Bar::funcName2()` apparently returns a null pointer.

Comment: Are both the this pointers different ? Thought of it just now.

Comment: Also, if you have two different objects (no matter the class), then the `this` pointer in each object will be different. The`this` pointer points to the current object, and will be different even in two objects of the same class.

Comment: Of course the pointers are different.  `Bar::funcName2()` is meant to be called on a `Bar` instance, while `Foo::funcName1()` should be called on a `Foo` instance.  Unless one is a subclass of the other (or something like that), they can't have the same address.

Comment: It's hard to know if you ask about the `this` pointer, or about the crash. What is it you want help with?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the Q's title: Your are calling methods on different objects. `this` points to the current object and hence can change there. [Here is an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157104/c-pointer-multi-inheritance-fun)

To answer your specific segfault: I'm assuming `funcName2` returns a `nullptr`. You should check that, before invoking `calledFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding redundant...

`this` points to the object on which you're calling a method. If you have two objects, and you call a method on both of them, they will both have a different `this` pointer.

In your code, funcName2() returns a NULL pointer. As a result, you're calling a method on a NULL object. Even so, it just so happens that the method returns something, but since you've already dereferenced a NULL pointer, your program's behaviour is now undefined.

You should ensure you don't dereference a NULL pointer. Two options:

- Make `funcName2()` not return `NULL`
- Make sure that your calling function verifies that the return value of `funcName2()` is not `NULL` before trying to do anything with it.